# Order of operations for Mortgage formula

Tags: polynomials

I'm trying to figure out how the Mortgage formula works. When the fixed monthly payment is defined as $E$, monthly interest as $b$, total loan as $U$, the number of payments as $p$, the formula should look like this.

$$E = U\frac{b(1 + b)^p}{(1 + b)^p-1}$$
Let's say that there is someone whose total loan is $\$1000$, interest is $5\%$, and the number of payments is $24$ ($24$ months).

When I tried to calculate it according to the formula, it went like this.

$$\begin{align}E &= 1000 [0.05 (1 + 0.05)^24] / [(1+0.05)^24-1]\\&= 1000[0.0525^24] / [1.05^23]\\&= 1000 [1.92230....] / [3.071524....]\\&= 1922.30... / 3.071524...\\&= 625.84...\end{align}$$

However, when I used a calculator tool such as [this website](https://www.mortgagecalculator.org/), the result was $\$43.87$.
(I entered $0$ for Home Value, Down payment, Property Tax, PMI, Home Ins, Monthly HOA)

I can also tell by common sense that it doesn't make sense to pay 625 dollars each month when the total loan is 1000 dollars, whereas it's reasonable to pay $43.87 each month, so I assume that the result I got from the calculator website is correct and something went wrong when I was manually calculating in the formula above.

But I don't know where it went wrong. Maybe was it because of a wrong order of operations? But I believe I followed the [rules of Grouping Symbols and Order of Operations](https://www.cliffsnotes.com/study-guides/basic-math/basic-math-and-pre-algebra/preliminaries/grouping-symbols-and-order-of-operations#:%7E:text=Three%20common%20types%20of%20grouping,order%20to%20simplify%20the%20problem.).

Comment: Maybe try asking at https://quant.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.